# How do you find the matrix which represents a reflection in the line y=mx?

Tags: matrices

What's the method behind finding such a matrix? Thanks

Comment: In $\mathbb{R}^3$ or $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Comment: You could think about eigenvectors and eigenvalues.  The vector $\left<1,m\right>$ would be fixed and the perpendicular vector $\left<-m,1\right>$ would be flipped.

Answer (score 1):

Reflections of the basis vectors (as always the images in any linear map) gives the columns of the matrix of the map.